# login screen talker; what is it?

Tags: 12.04, login

Have just downloaded 12.04 from the Costa Rica Server.

At login a voice comes on in English and repeats the password keys--very disturbing.

Avast and ClamTK found nothing.

What is going on?

Answer (score 3):

That's probably an activated Universal Access -> Screen Reader setting.

Settings -> Universal Access -> switch off the Screen Reader option.

Comment: Thank you. Removed Orca screen Reader and problem solved.

Comment: Glad I could help.